# VBA Vlookup Issues

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My current project has a main-input page, which requires Client ID, Currency, and Market. For each client there are different circumstances and different outputs of commission % and MIN/MAX commissions.

When I use Vlookup to search for (A2&B2&C2), it searches for CLIENTIDCURRENCYMARKET, instead of CLIENT CURRENCY MARKET, and thus it locate anything.

**General idea for code:**

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2;'Spec. Klienti - Horiz'!B2:T75;4;FALSE)
```

**Main-input page** *(Client ID, Currency, and Market) are the input values, MIN and % is where I need it to return the MIN/% of that specific Client.*
[image]

**Vlookup search table is here (different sheet)**
[image]

Comment: What are you exactly looking for in the table, a text that contains `CLIENT CURRENCY MARKET`? `=VLOOKUP()` looks for a match in the first column.

Comment: @RowenChumacera I'm trying to use the inputed Client ID, Currency, and Market to search for the MIN/% from the second-image table. Could I use something other than Vlookup?

Comment: Your search table is not in a good format to search for the values you want. Does it have to be structured like that?

Comment: @RobAnthony Would prefer it to be in this format, so that it could be easier to see what markets are under what client.

Comment: Then you will need to write some VBA to find the data you want, a simple Vlookup won't do it.

Comment: If you changed the format of the table slightly so that each value was on one line (and the data repeated it would work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use VLookup in the way you want to, you would need to change the format of the lookup table to this:

```
> Ind             ClientID    Currency    %      Min    Market
> 
> 111111EURDE     111111      EUR         0.1%   30     DE
> 
> 111111EURFR     111111      EUR         0.1%   30     FR
> 
> 111111EURNL     111111      EUR         0.1%   30     NL
```

ie ONE row per piece of data. The first column is to allow the use of VLookup in the way you want it to work.

You can still read the table but it does repeat a lot of the data (which is not good practice but works)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be searching for 'CLIENT CURRENCY MARKET', you should add spaces between the text. Try this:

=VLOOKUP(A2&" "&B2&" "&C2;'Spec. Klienti - Horiz'!B2:T75;4;FALSE)

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. Ignores the spacing and still searches for the same thing.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you wanted to search in multiple columns. It's not really clear from the question, but if you are searching for numbers (no text) the function:
=SUMIFS()
might be helpful. This function will sum the information of one column while looking for the combination of input values. This will however only work when the combination of input values is unique.